# Table-driven design in R

Tags: r

I do a fair bit of routine reporting on datasets with a large number of parameters. This involves pulling data from a database (SQL Query), tidying up the data (transpose, filter, sometime transform by log(x) or 1/x), plotting the data with spec lines (trend charts, distribution charts, 2D scatter plots), and reporting statistics (mean, stdev, but also k, Cp, Cpk which requires spec limits).

**Because the number of parameters can be large I like to use a table to encode any values associated with each parameter.** This "parm table" has one row per parameter and various columns: e.g., parm_name, parm_label, lower_spec_limit, target, upper_spec_limit, lower_filter_limit, upper_filter_limit, lower_axis_limit, upper_axis_limit.

I parse the table to assemble a list of parameters to pull from the database and build an SQL query around this. I refer to the filter limits in the table when filtering data. And to the spec limits when plotting data. I also tend to have columns that put the parameters into groups so I can filter on these columns to pick which parms to report on.

***This table-driven approach has worked well for me in SAS but I have yet to get it running in R.***

For example, I have a SAS macro that will plot `parmA` vs `parmB` with appropriate axes and spec limits on the plot. It encodes my preferences for the look of the plot and parses the data table for spec limits and such. I just feed it the names of the parameters.

I've written R code to make the same plot with ggplot2 where I hard-code parameter names, limits, etc. When I try to abstract out the details I run into a wall of confusion around SE vs NSE. I'd like to call `f(parmA, parmB)` and end up with a ggplot2 call with the right spec lines and axis limits looked up from my table but I haven't figured out how to get there.

In a typical SAS script I make a series of calls to these plotting macros, each time requesting a different plot. In my more developed scripts I have a second table that encodes a list of plots to make (this can be as simple as two columns with x and y parms) and my SAS code reads this table and generates the plotting calls.

I've tried searching for examples of R code that implements this approach but failed. Any pointers would be appreciated. I wonder if this approach to the problem is inherently awkward in R and I should be thinking about it another way entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put together a very simple example of the situation you described.  Without some code to work from, it is difficult to provide a more precise answer.  However hopefully this example is enough to get you started.  If you have any questions please let me know.

```
PlotingParameters <- data.frame(parm_name = c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"), 
                                  xmin = c(0, 2), 
                                  xmax = c(3, 5))

myPlotFuction <- function(myparm_name, myPlotingParameters = PlotingParameters){ #you must be sure your parameter table is within the enviroment of your function
  myXmin <- myPlotingParameters$xmin[myPlotingParameters$parm_name == myparm_name]
  myXmax <- myPlotingParameters$xmax[myPlotingParameters$parm_name == myparm_name]
  g <- ggplot(data = iris, aes_string(x = myparm_name, y = "Petal.Width")) + #you can use aes_string to reference columns using strings
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(myXmin, myXmax))
  print(g)  
}

myPlotFuction("Sepal.Width")
```

As a side note, in R it might be slightly less awkward to build a table with all of the parameters you need to build your graph and then have a generic plot function applied to each row of the table - rather than passing just some of the parameters to the table and then looking the others up.  Here is a quick example:

```
myPlotFuction2 <- function(myparm_name, myXmin, myXmax){ #you must be sure your parameter table is within the enviroment of your function
  g <- ggplot(data = iris, aes_string(x = myparm_name, y = "Petal.Width")) + #you can use aes_string to use strings to reference columns
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(myXmin, myXmax))
  print(g)  
}

apply(PlotingParameters, 1, function(x) myPlotFuction2(x["parm_name"], as.numeric(x["xmin"]) , as.numeric(x["xmax"])))
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! Your answer got me going in the right direction although I ended up with a slightly different implementation. I will post it as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's answer really pointed me in the right direction. Still, **I prefer to pass variable names in function calls as bare expressions rather than strings.** Mostly this is about making my code easier to type and read. So I ended up with a different implementation that is outlined below.

**To handle bare variable expressions I use the quosure functions defined in {rlang}.** These are supported by current versions of {ggplot2} and other {tidyverse} packages. A full function call looks like this (it gets simpler in the example at the bottom of this answer):

```
mygplot(df = iris, xx = Sepal.Width, yy = Sepal.Length, zz = Species, lf = parmspec)
```

Within the plotting function each parameter expression is put into a quosure:

```
xx <- enquo(xx)
yy <- enquo(yy)
zz <- enquo(zz)
```

These can be individual variables or an expression that is evaluated in the context of the dataset. For example, you can specify a combination of factors: `interaction(aspect1, aspect2)`.

For the parameter lookup these quosures are converted into strings:

```
xn <- quo_name(xx)
yn <- quo_name(yy)
```

Now we can do lookups using the base subset syntax (as in Ian's answer):

```
xmin <- lf$min [lf$name == xn]
xmax <- lf$max [lf$name == xn]
```

When creating {ggplot2} objects we use `aes_` and the bare quosure:

```
ggplot(df, aes_(x = xx, y = yy))
```

*That's it.* I included a full example below since there are a few more tricks that help make it all work. Specifically, we want to handle missing values in the parameter table. Also, to generate many similar plots we define a function operator that returns a simplified plotting function with some of the arguments filled in. See the code comments for details.

```
require(rlang)
require(ggplot2)

# Set scale limits and optionally apply a translation.
# Silently default to the identity translation if none is specified.
scale_trans <- function(scale_func, min, max, trans) {
  if(is.na(trans)) trans <- "identity"
  scale_func(limits = c(min, max), trans = trans)
}

# Annotate plot with vertical spec lines.
# Handle missing values silently.
geom_vspec <- function(lsl, tgt, usl) {
  list(
    if (!is.na(lsl)) geom_vline(xintercept = lsl),
    if (!is.na(tgt)) geom_vline(xintercept = tgt, linetype = 2),
    if (!is.na(usl)) geom_vline(xintercept = usl)
  )
}

# Annotate plot with horizontal spec lines.
# Handle missing values silently.
geom_hspec <- function(lsl, tgt, usl) {
  list(
    if (!is.na(lsl)) geom_hline(yintercept = lsl),
    if (!is.na(tgt)) geom_hline(yintercept = tgt, linetype = 2),
    if (!is.na(usl)) geom_hline(yintercept = usl)
  )
}

# Create trend chart: yy vs xx colored by ff.
# Apply plot limits and specs as found in lf.
# Quote inputs to support ggplot2 NSE.
mygplot <- function(df, xx, yy, zz, lf) {
  xx <- enquo(xx)
  yy <- enquo(yy)
  zz <- enquo(zz)
  xn <- quo_name(xx)
  yn <- quo_name(yy)
  xmin   <- lf$min  [lf$name == xn]
  xmax   <- lf$max  [lf$name == xn]
  xtrans <- lf$trans[lf$name == xn]
  xlsl   <- lf$lsl [lf$name == xn]
  xtgt   <- lf$tgt [lf$name == xn]
  xusl   <- lf$usl [lf$name == xn]
  ymin   <- lf$min  [lf$name == yn]
  ymax   <- lf$max  [lf$name == yn]
  ytrans <- lf$trans[lf$name == yn]
  ylsl   <- lf$lsl [lf$name == yn]
  ytgt   <- lf$tgt [lf$name == yn]
  yusl   <- lf$usl [lf$name == yn]
  ggplot(df, aes_(x = xx, y = yy)) +
    geom_point(aes_(color = zz)) + 
    scale_trans(scale_y_continuous, ymin, ymax, ytrans) + geom_hspec(ylsl, ytgt, yusl) + 
    scale_trans(scale_x_continuous, xmin, xmax, xtrans) + geom_vspec(xlsl, xtgt, xusl)
}

# This function operator enables shorthand code when making multiple calls to a
# plot function with the same dataframe, x-axis, fill color, and limits file.
call.mygplot <- function(df, zz, lf, f = mygplot) {
  zz = enquo(zz)
  function(...) {
    f(df = df, ..., zz = UQ(zz), lf = lf)
  }
}

# Specify the parameter specs (for many specs this would be read in from a file)
parmspec <- data.frame(
  name  = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), 
  min   = c(4.0, 2.0, 0.5, 0.0), 
  max   = c(8.0, 4.5, 7.5, 3.0),
  trans = c( NA,  NA,  NA,  NA),
  lsl   = c(5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0),
  tgt   = c(6.0, 3.5, 4.0, 1.5),
  usl   = c(7.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0))

# We will create multiple plots of iris by Species so lets use a shorthand
mygplot2 <- call.mygplot(iris, Species, parmspec)
mygplot2(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)
mygplot2(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
```